# Does salesforce update LastRunDate on report when we execute report via API (HTTP) and analytics API

Tags: reporting, analytics

Does salesforce update LastRunDate field on report when we execute report via API (HTTP) and analytics API

basically wanted to clean some reports in org, but do not want to delete reports which are being used via API.

HTTP API - mean when we simply try to send HTTP get request to report

Analytics API - /services/data/v29.0/analytics/reports/{Report Id}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Analytics API does *not update* the Last Viewed Date or Last Run Date fields of reports. There is no "API-compatible" means of updating those values. The best bet would be to update any APIs you are using to run the report directly (e.g. regular HTTP GET using /{ReportId} instead of /services/data/v29.0/analytics/reports/{ReportId}) each time you also use the Analytics API. You can use your session ID from the API login as a valid session key, so you don't need to double up on logins.